# How can I recursive traverse an XML-File in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, xpath, touchxml

I got the following XML-Structure:

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <name>Category_1</name>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <SubCategories>
            <category>
                <name>Category_2</name>
                <ID>101</ID>
                <SubCategory>
                    <category>
                        <name>Category_3</name>
                        <ID>102</ID>
                        <SubCategory></SubCategory>
                    </category>
                </SubCategory>
            </category>
        </SubCategories>
    </category>
</categories>
```

I want to parse this file and write every element into a database. I use TouchXML to do the parsing because it is fast and easy to use but I don't know if is the right parser. It would be great if someone can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "native Cocoa" way to parse XML is with an [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class).

On the other hand, if you're familiar with TouchXML and it's "fast and easy to use", are you sure you need to switch to something else?